# TableView Empty in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I need help for implement some `UIViewController` with `TableView` in `UIPageViewController`

This is my current code, but not works. Some `UIViewController` appear but the `TableView` is empty, no cells.

**APageViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  pages = [NSMutableArray array];

  self.delegate = self;
  self.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [self setupPageViewController];
}

- (void)setupPageViewController{

  for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {
    AViewControllerWithTableView *detail = (AViewControllerWithTableView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCID"];
    [detail reloadTableView:items[i]]; // tableview reload data here
    [pages addObject:detail];
  }

  [self setViewControllers:@[pages[0]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDataSource

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger currentIndex = [pages indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSInteger previousIndex = currentIndex-1;
    if (previousIndex < 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    return pages[previousIndex];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSInteger currentIndex = [pages indexOfObject:viewController];
    NSInteger nextIndex = currentIndex+1;
    if (nextIndex > pages.count - 1) {
        return nil;
    }

    return pages[nextIndex];
}
```

**AViewControllerWithTableView**

```
@implementation AViewControllerWithTableView{
    NSMutableArray *details;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    details = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)reloadTableView:(NSDictionary *)detail{

  if([detail.type isEqualToString:@"A"]){
    [details addObject:something];
  } else if([detail.type isEqualToString:@"B"]){
    [details addObject:something];
  } else if([detail.type isEqualToString:@"C"]){
    [details addObject:something];
  } else {
    [details addObject:something];
  }

  [self.detailTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  NSLog(@"details: %@", details); // details always empty / @[]
  return details.count;
}
```

tableview is empty, no cells.

How you implement this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue :

You are setting

```
details = [NSMutableArray array];
```

in the viewDidLoad of your tableView Controller which gets called once PageViewController loads your tableView.

but you are sending data to your tableView Controller by calling `[detail reloadTableView:items[i]];` even before tableView is loaded.

So either you were calling `reloadTableView` while details was always nil
or even if it was populated your statement `details = [NSMutableArray array];` in viewDidLoad now cleared it :)

Solution :

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {
    AViewControllerWithTableView *detail = (AViewControllerWithTableView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCID"];
    if(detail.details == nil) {
        detail.details = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [detail.details.addObject:items[i]];
    [pages addObject:detail];
  }
```

Finally 
remove `details = [NSMutableArray array];` from viewDidLoad of your tableView

Comment: @hezron : Am glad it helped you :)